# Why is the image looking good on a computer and mobile but not on a tablet?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I’m working on a digital art exhibition that will combine both musicd, images and audio descriptions of the pictures.
It is a Laravel project with Bootstrap and I’m having a little difficulty with the responsiveness of the pictures.
Since I am totally blind since birth, it is quite hard to work with images since I obviously can’t see what I’m doing. 
My sighted friends has told me that the images look fine on mobile and computer, but on the tablet/iPad, they are too large and it is not possible to zoom.
I can’t get my head around why it is not working as expected.
Here is my head tag where I include the bootstrap packages:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>


<title>Circus Freak</title>
<style>
@font-face {
src: url('/../Fonts/Circus.ttf');
font-family: "circus";
}
body {
font-family: arial;
}
</style>
</head>
```

And here is the exhibition page where the images are shown, along with the controls to choose the music and the audio description of the different pictures. Sorry that the labels are in swedish.

```
<x-layout>
<div class="container">
<h1>VÄLKOMMEN TILL UTSTÄLLNINGEN</h1>
<H2>
Välj den tavla du vill se
</H2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Tavlor">
<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="switchPictures(1)" >Apan</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="switchPictures(2)" >Hunden</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="switchPictures(3)" >Fågeln</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="switchPictures(4)">Pandan</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="switchPictures(5)">Clownen</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="switchPictures(6)">Hästen</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<h2>Lyssna på den aktuella tavlans musik</h2>
<audio id="music" tilte="musik" controls>
  <source src="../audio/music1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>
<div class="col">
<h2>Lyssna på syntolkningen av aktuell tavla</h2>
<audio id="desc" tilte="Syntolkning" controls>
  <source src="../audio/desc1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<img id="picture" src="../images/picture1.jpg" alt="Nu visas: Tavla 1 - Apan" class="img-fluid">
</div>
</x-layout>
```

In my Public/Css/App.css file, I have the following line thatI guess is created by Laravel:

```
img,
svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Could that be a problem in any way?
Feeling totally lost right now! :)

The JavaScript to choose between images and music files is located in a different file, but I don’t think that it’s the JS that’s causing the issue here.

The site is actually already published on a domain, so if you want to see the images in action you can go to:
https://circusfreak.se/exhibition/index

Here is a screen shot of what the image looks like on the iPad:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9C2i.jpg)
As I understand it, the image looks good in portrait but not in landscape mode.
Please tell me if you need to see something else in the project to fully understand the context!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

All the best!

Comment: What does your app.css look like? Also could you put an example of the image in the above question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated the post with a link to the site, and a line of code in my Public/Css/App.css that might be causing a problem. I didn't wanna post the whole App.css since it includes a lot of classes and definitions, probably created by Bootstrap. But please tell me if you need to see something more from the project! Thanks very much!

Comment: I checked the page and also the image. It seems to be working fine. What tablet device are you using to test and in what orientation? Can you use the browser's device emulation to check the image - maybe post screenshots of the issue? Without being able to reproduce the issue it is difficult to help - sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I've checked with my friend and as I understand it, the image looks good when the tablet is in portrait mode but not in landscape. I've added a screen shot in the post above that shows the image on the iPad. Is it possible to get the image to work in both portrait and landscape? All the best!

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the landscape mode, the image is "too big" or overflows in the vertical direction. Is this is the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use CSS media queries which target specific orientation like

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    img {
        max-height: 100%;
    }
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will definitely try that! If I insert these media queries, can I keep the Bootstrap classes for the image and the div surrounding it, or do I need to remove those? If I need to remove them, what do I need to do to get the same style of the image as it has now? Hope you understand what I mean, sorry if the questions is at a basic level, but these visual aspects are really hard to grasp, for natural reasons maybe. :)

Comment: You do not need to remove the Bootstrap classes. It depends on where you place the custom CSS with respect to the page as compared to the Bootstrap class. If you put the custom css after the import of the Bootstrap css, it will override it. Hence the name "cascading" in cascading style sheets. In some rare cases it Bootstrap still may enforce its styling but you can override it with the `!important` keyword see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Also, you can use your browser's "inspect" feature to see what classes are being applied and what the exact css is for that class.